# How to detect java global object has risk not being closed

Tags: java, memory-leaks, global-variables

Our code has a commonly used utility that creates thread level global object. Say

```
GlobalObject.open(String ID);
```

And it will rely on explicitly ClobalObject.close(String ID); to make the object close(garbage collection).

And also, if the code is like:

```
GlobalObject.open(String ID);
//some computation
ClobalObject.close(String ID);
```

If there is Exception throw in the "some computation" part, a close statement will never reach and causing the memory leak.

Anyway can programmatically detecting whether the ClobalObject.close is there and explicitly in the finally block so it can always be executed?

Thanks

Comment: try with ressources is what you need

Comment: Try-with-resources using the `AutoCloseable` interface if Java 7+ is allowed. Otherwise, this is the classic purpose of the `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks guys. My purpose is to asking for audit whether there is improper usage. Like test suit, findbugs? etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really need is a source code analyser like [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) (or it's successor [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/)) & [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) (don't choose, you need both, there is plugins for all popular IDEs), or just Sonar (which is basically a server designed to hold and display the results of those two, in which case you'll need to have continuous integration to make sure it gets updated often), so you can find programming mistakes like this one.However, I'll think you may have to create a custom rule for your case, which I don't know how hard it can be.

In case you really want to do it programmatically at runtime, you could do that with a Java agent, and JVMTI but it's going to be very complicated unless you are very familiar with all the concepts of the JVM.

Another idea, if you are okay for changing the architecture of your project a little, instead of having developers do GlobalState.open(String ID) and then close(String ID), use aspects. What I mean is create an annotation like @GlobalState(String ID) that will tell that before opening this method you must open ID and close it afterwards, this way you can have only one interceptor that will do the open() and close(), which make it easier for developers and safer. If ID is not a constant you can also have another annotation on one of the parameter, like @GlobalStateId that your interceptor can use to know which value to use for ID.

Comment: Thanks. I think you make sense. I will enable the source code analyzer for our source code.

Comment: @AmyLiu Just to point out that FindBugs is all but dead, hasn't been updated for over three years, and doesn't offer for support Java 9 or Java 10 features. It's successor is [SpotBugs](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/).

Comment: @skomisa Thx for the info, I didn't knew that, I'm still using Findbugs, I should probably switch. I updated my answer accordingly.